# React component wrapped in useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So, from what I understand from the official React docs, when trying to prevent a Child component of a certain Parent to re-render, you need to wrap the child in a useMemo, then wrap the functions inside the Parent, that are passed down to the Child in a useCallback, that being said, what is the point of this implementation:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [isFiltersOpen, setIsFiltersOpen ] = useState(false);

  const hasNoDevices = someHookReturnFromApi();
  const hasDevices = someHookReturnFromApi();
  const areAllDevicesLoaded = anotherHookButCallsApiForData();
  const missingOtherStuff = thisHookChecksIfSomeApisAreDoneLoading();
  const onSomething = useCallback(() => console.log(hasNoDevices), [hasNoDevices]);
  const sortedData = useMemo(() => hasDevices.sort(// do some sorts...));
  const filters = filtersFromApi();
  
  const onClosePanel = () =>  setIsFiltersOpen(false);

  const renderSection = useCallback(() => {
    if (hasNoDevices) {
      return (
        <EmptyState
          areAllDevicesLoaded={areAllDevicesLoaded}
          subtitle={t('just.a.translation')}
        />
      );
    }

    if (missingOtherStuff) {
      return (
        <SectionEmptyState onSomething={onSomething} />
      );
    }

    return (
      <>
        <SectionData
          sortedData={sortedData}
          hasDevices={hasDevices}
        />

        <div>
          {isFiltersOpen && <Panel isOpen={isOpen} filters={filters} onClose={onClosePanel} />}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }, [hasDevices, hasNoDevices, sortedData, areAllDevicesLoaded, onSomething, isFiltersOpen, isOpen, filters, onClosePanel]);

return (
 <>
   <h1>Parent component</h1>
   {renderSection()}
 </>
);
```

I mean **useCallback**, returns the same function, same reference, so how does this help? Does it have something to do with memory allocation? So that when the parent re-renders, another space in the memory won't be taken up to create another reference to all of that?

### Edit

Lots of good information in the comments. The only thing is, I don't think my question is clear enough, so I'll try to shorten it!

My question boils down to, is there any meaning in using useCallback, on a child component, `const componentVariable = useCallback(() => <SomeComponentMaybeWithProps />, [])`, that will sit inside of the render of its parent component, as long as that parent component is not wrapped in a `memo`?

Comment: Please use memo instead of useCallback for preventing re-render component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

useCallback caches your function and its dependencies so that it won't re-render when said dependencies haven't changed (following renders compare current to previous dependencies). So yes, this is a simple **performance optimization**.

This also exactly what is happening in your example: `renderSection` will stay the same until one or more of `[hasDevices, hasNoDevices, sortedData, areAllDevicesLoaded, onSomething, isFiltersOpen, isOpen, filters, onClosePanel]` have changed.

You could think about implementing **memo** https://react.dev/reference/react/memo to not only cache the function but also skip re-rendering of `{renderSection()}` entirely when the function hasn't changed.

Comment: for me, this is the most on point answer until now, I just wish I had some docs or examples of how this is efficient, because it seems weird, if ```useCallback``` works on its own like that, while storing a ```component``` inside a ```variable```, then what is the point of ```memo```? Its a little unclear to me

Comment: It's important to understand that `useCallback` only stores a function. `{renderSection()}` calls the function which then returns a component, but that component is not cached at all. This is where memo comes into play - a way to cache (memoize) the returned component of `renderSection()`.

Comment: So basically, for implementations such as above, useCallback is pointless, because it does not store any or the components, so there is no performance gain, right? Is there any documentation for this? Its incredible to me that I can't find a discussion about this anywhere... or maybe I don't know what to look for.

Comment: React's compiler has some interesting changes regarding ```useMemo``` ```useCallback``` and ```memo```.
Check here: https://react.dev/blog/2024/02/15/react-labs-what-we-have-been-working-on-february-2024#react-compiler

Answer (score 1):

Here is the difference on when to use them.

`useMemo`

> It should be used when there are expensive calculations that needs to be done. (eg: assume you have a long list of calculations to be done which slows your js thread if there are multiple re-renders to the component).

What you are referring to as wrapping of the component should be `memo` and not `useMemo` which when used without any equality parameter shallow compares the props of the component wrapped with it and based on the comparison if both are same it returns the previous result (no-rerender), if there is a change it re-renders the said comparison.

`useCallback`

> In react on every re-render all the variable and function inside it is re-computed hence the function reference changes everytime. If you pass it to a `memo`-ed component it will possibly re-render since the function reference changes. To avoid that you can use `useCallback` which will only change its reference on dependency change provided to it. Also note that if any value like any state is being used inside it which is not added to the dependency chain it will cause issue since the value won't be updated and have stale values when the function gets called.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd refactor your snippet:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [isFiltersOpen, setIsFiltersOpen ] = useState(false);

  const hasNoDevices = someHookReturnFromApi();
  const hasDevices = someHookReturnFromApi();
  const areAllDevicesLoaded = anotherHookButCallsApiForData();
  const missingOtherStuff = thisHookChecksIfSomeApisAreDoneLoading();
  const onSomething = useCallback(() => console.log(hasNoDevices), [hasNoDevices]);
  const sortedData = useMemo(() => hasDevices.sort(// do some sorts...));
  const filters = filtersFromApi();
  
  const onClosePanel = useCallback(() => setIsFiltersOpen(false), []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Parent component</h1>
      {hasNoDevices && !missingOtherStuff && (
        <EmptyState
          areAllDevicesLoaded={areAllDevicesLoaded}
          subtitle={t('just.a.translation')}
        />
      )}
      {!hasNoDevices && missingOtherStuff && (
        <SectionEmptyState onSomething={onSomething} />
      )}
      {!hasNoDevices && !missingOtherStuff && (
        <>
          <SectionData
            sortedData={sortedData}
            hasDevices={hasDevices}
          />
          <div>
            {isFiltersOpen && <Panel isOpen={isOpen} filters={filters} onClose={onClosePanel} />}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Everything that is passed to the child components (`EmptyState`, `SectionEmptyState`, `SectionData`, `Panel`) is already memoized, except `onClosePanel` (a callback without dependencies). It kind of looked like you were trying to do what React does on its own already. You only need to worry about the props these child components receive. Making sure these props are memoized and not re-created with new references whenever `ParentComponent` renders is enough afaik.

It might be style preference, but several returns in a component are a bit hard to read. Conditionals in JSX instead keep the markup grouped together.